# WSO2 IS Create a secondary user store using internal LDAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to organize users in WSO2 IS 5.9 in several user stores (secondaries). Can I do this using the WSO2 IS internal LDAP? I do not have any other external user store (ldap, ad, ...)

About this way to organize users, is there another way to group users in the primary user store, so that I can use a specific user store/group with a defined service provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the first question, the answer is no. Internal embedded LDAP is the primary user store. You cannot use that as the secondary user store. Also, it is not recommended to use embedded LDAP in production. So it will be good to set up an external LDAP server so you can connect to that using identity server and make it the user store. [1]

About the second question, my suggestion is when creating an SP there is a hybrid role that creates automatically for that service provider. You can assign that role to users that you need to group based on the service provider. [2]

[1]. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores/

[2]. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-roles-and-permissions-for-a-service-provider/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a straight answer to your question. But just mentioning in case if it helps.

You may want to check tenancy in WSO2 IS. It internally uses the same LDAP, but creates isolated OUs for each tenant within the LDAP.